# Can IRetryAnalyzer be implemented without @Test annotation?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, selenide

My project is using cucumber and testng.@Test annotation is not being used anywhere in the project. I Want to re run the failed test scenarios automatically during execution.
Have tried using the rerun plugin to create failed scenarios text file and re run them using a different cucumber runner file.

Have seen examples where we can use the IRetryAnalyzer, but they all include the use of @Test annotation.
Is it possible to use IRetryAnalyzer without the @Test annotation?